# HTML screen scraper

Tags: html, browser, web-scraping

Is there a screen scraper that I can run through a browser that could find an element on the page (a div or image etc) and tell me what that element rendered styles are? So it would change if the browser width were adjusted. Effectively the computed styles you can see in chrome dev tools?

Comment: There are a lot of options, are you looking for an external tool like Selenium? Or some kind of a browser extension?

Comment: @AdiBnaya I'm not sure. I was thinking about something that could look down through the images and seeing what size the images were and what width they were set too for a particular screen sizem as a way to identify images to be resized to improve performance

Comment: look at the [Keyframes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyframes/dalaiblmpeklkjnpeocmaojcfldmbfck?hl=en) Chrome extension to see if it can help you achieve what you need